# Email label vs local-part and hyphens

Tags: email, rfc5322

I've been reading through RFC, summaries, wikipedia, etc.  I'm super confused about local-part vs labels.  It seems to me that the local-part is before the @.  That much seems straightforward.  The label is any part of the domain separated by a dot.  But it seems to me that some places also refer to the local-part as a label.  And that is very confusing within the context of where hyphens are allowed.  So specifically what is a label?

And with that, which of these are valid email address (if any)?

```
-bobross@painting.com
bobross-@painting.com
bobross@-painting.com
bobross@painting-.com
```

My understanding is that a label can neither end or begin with a hyphen and it must not contain two consecutive hyphens.  Am I missing anything with that?

Bonus points - there are a number of special characters allowed in the local-part, but some sources I've seen say that the local-part must end in an alphanumeric character, but I'm not actually seeing that in any standard..am I missing it or can it end with one of the allowed characters?

Comment: you obviously didn't read much. Right from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address): `An email address such as John.Smith@example.com is made up of a local-part, an @ symbol, then a case-insensitive domain.`

Comment: Stick to the contents of the RFC, if somebody sais anything different, they are wrong. RFC is always right.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, and none of those use the term label.  And like I mentioned, my confusion comes from sources seeming to use label for both the local-part and the domain.  So that's where my question lies.  Your reiteration of that sentence literally does nothing to help my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [rfc5321, section 2.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.5):

```
A domain name (or often just a "domain") consists of one or more
components, separated by dots if more than one appears.  In the case
of a top-level domain used by itself in an email address, a single
string is used without any dots.  This makes the requirement,
described in more detail below, that only fully-qualified domain
names appear in SMTP transactions on the public Internet,
particularly important where top-level domains are involved.  These
components ("labels" in DNS terminology, RFC 1035 [2]) are restricted
for SMTP purposes to consist of a sequence of letters, digits, and
hyphens drawn from the ASCII character set [6].  Domain names are
used as names of hosts and of other entities in the domain name
hierarchy.  For example, a domain may refer to an alias (label of a
CNAME RR) or the label of Mail eXchanger records to be used to
deliver mail instead of representing a host name.  See RFC 1035 [2]
and Section 5 of this specification.
```

In other words, a domain of `abc.def.xyz` is made up of 3 *components* (aka *labels*): `abc`, `def`, and `xyz`. Each of these *labels* is only allowed to contain letters, digits, and hyphens. For a more specific definition, we must check the ABNF grammar in the [Command Argument Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.2) section because what we really care about is the syntax of the arguments to the `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO` commands (aka the "email address" tokens in layman's terms).

An "email address" is actually referred to as a `Mailbox` in the SMTP specification:

```
Mailbox        = Local-part "@" ( Domain / address-literal )
```

Now to look at the definition of a `Local-part` token:

```
Local-part     = Dot-string / Quoted-string
               ; MAY be case-sensitive


Dot-string     = Atom *("."  Atom)

Atom           = 1*atext
```

To get the definition of `atext`, we need to look at the [Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). Specifically, we need to look at [section 3.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.3):

```
atext           =   ALPHA / DIGIT /    ; Printable US-ASCII
                    "!" / "#" /        ;  characters not including
                    "$" / "%" /        ;  specials.  Used for atoms.
                    "&" / "'" /
                    "*" / "+" /
                    "-" / "/" /
                    "=" / "?" /
                    "^" / "_" /
                    "`" / "{" /
                    "|" / "}" /
                    "~"
```

(Note: I've left out the definition of a `Quoted-string` because it's irrelevant to your question.)

Now let's check out the definition of a `Domain`:

```
Domain         = sub-domain *("." sub-domain)

sub-domain     = Let-dig [Ldh-str]

Let-dig        = ALPHA / DIGIT

Ldh-str        = *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" ) Let-dig
```

What we see here is that a *label* is the same thing as a `sub-domain` token, but here we also see that *labels* (aka `sub-domain`'s) of a `Domain` cannot start or end with a hyphen.

We can also see that a `sub-domain` token is actually a subset of the allowable characters in an `Atom` and so the characters allowed in each *component* of a `Local-part` are not the same as those allowed in each *component* of a `Domain`.

To answer your other questions:

> And with that, which of these are valid email address (if any)?

```
-bobross@painting.com [VALID]
bobross-@painting.com [VALID]
bobross@-painting.com [INVALID]
bobross@painting-.com [INVALID]
```

> My understanding is that a label can neither end or begin with a hyphen and it must not contain two consecutive hyphens. Am I missing anything with that?

Let's use the term `sub-domain` to make things less confusing.

Yes, that is correct.

> Bonus points - there are a number of special characters allowed in the local-part, but some sources I've seen say that the local-part must end in an alphanumeric character, but I'm not actually seeing that in any standard..am I missing it or can it end with one of the allowed characters?

Well, according to the ABNF grammar of rfc5322, a `Local-part` can both start *and* end with a hyphen.